# Eclipse CDT Source->Implement Method generates code not following defined code style

Tags: c++, eclipse, coding-style, eclipse-cdt

I am using Source->Implement Method sometimes, but I noticed that the generated code does not follow the defined code style from the preferences (the style is applied when I use Source->Format correctly) - Is there some setting I missed or is that a bug?

Using Eclipse Version 3.5.2 and CDT 6.0.2 on Ubuntu Linux 10.04 LTS.

Example: we defined the opening { to be on the same line as the class/method definition, but Implement Method puts it on the following line.

Comment: CDT implements only a minor subset of Eclipse features. Don't expect so much.

Comment: I don't but it's clearly something they overlooked. If they add code automatically, why not run it through the formatter (which they support) first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried, and I do not encounter this issue (I am using Eclipse 3.3, 3.4 and 3.6).

I don't know if you are aware of this Eclipse feature, but in `Preferences > Java > Editor > Save actions`, you can define the list of actions that are automatically run when you save the Java class you are currently editing.

The interesting elements in this panel are the *Format source code* as well as the *Organize imports* actions.

---

Edit regarding the comments:

This problem seems to be related to the [Eclipse CDT plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt) which does not offer the `save actions` feature. I just had a look on CDT [version 7.0](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn70) and this feature has not been added unfortunately.

So I suggest that you log a bug in their [Bugzilla instance](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs) to report the problem you encounter with the `Impement method` feature. Eventually, you can also log an enhancement to add this `Save actions` in this plugin!

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about the C++ editor? That Save actions thing is not triggered when editing C++ files, and the C++ Save actions do not have a "Format source code" option.

Comment: @brandstaetter Oh, indeed, I was only talking about Java code. I do not use Eclipse for C++ development. So it seems to be a problem with the `CDT` plugin...

Comment: Too bad. I hope someone here uses CDT and can help me.

Comment: I had hoped that it was a problem on my side, not a bug/missing feature. I'll bugzilla it...